# Declarar tamaño de parametros en encabezado de Stored Procedures en SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedure

Tengo esté Store procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Proc_GuardarAccion(@iDowntimeID INT,@AccionTomada VARCHAR,@Responsable VARCHAR, @fechaIni date,@fechaFin date,@iAvance INT,
@file NVARCHAR, @Comment VARCHAR)
```

Al momento de ejecutarlo desde c# pues mando escribo el nombre del proc y los parametros

Proc_GuardarAccion('par1'.....)

Pero cuando reviso la informacion que se guardo, en los que son string solo me pone la primer letra, alguna idea de que pueda ser? deberia declarar el tamaño de cada parametro en el create procedure?

Comment: El primer parámetro no es un int?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que agregarle la longitud a cada variable

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Proc_GuardarAccion(
@iDowntimeID INT,
@AccionTomada VARCHAR(10),
@Responsable VARCHAR(10), 
@fechaIni date,
@fechaFin date,
@iAvance INT,
@file NVARCHAR(10), 
@Comment VARCHAR(10))
```

Naturalmente tomé el 10 como ejemplo y debes acondicionarlo a tus requerimientos.

Answer (score 1):

Según la [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> When n is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration
>   statement, the default length is 1.

Esa decir confirma tu diagnóstico, si no indicas el tamaño de un `VARCHAR` o `NVARCHAR` en una variable, el valor por defecto es 1. De forma que la solución pasa por darle el tamaño apropiado a los parámetros.